# Need to get height attribute value from an ifram and set parent element to contain it

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm going to be receiving some dynamically generated iframe content at a later date and trying to create a template that will comfortably fit the iframe no matter what height. So I want to write a jquery script that reads the value of the height attribute in the iframe so I can set the parent element to a corresponding size.

What I'm not sure how to do is access the height attribute in the iframe ... I'm assuming the easiest thing to do is run the script from the parent element to get the iframe height and then set it's own height . I also expect the iframes to be same domain so that won't be a problem.

```
<div class="parent_element" style="">
<!-- .parent_element {height: } should be set to 400px -->
<iframe src="" height="400"></iframe>
</div
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#parent_element").height($("iframe").height());
```

or:

```
$("#parent_element").height($("iframe").attr("height"));
```

Answer (score 0):

When the iframe src loads, resize the iframe height to match document (plus a little for scroll bars).

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('iframe').load( function() {
    //console.log($(this).contents().height() + ' is the height');
    $(this).height($(this).contents().height() + 25); // add some to the height to allow for horizontal scroll bars
  });
});
```